# Where to get the Oracle XML parsing jars for the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 11.2.0.2.0 and older

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

Trying to read some data stored in a Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2.0) database stored as the data type "XMLTYPE", using the JDBC driver.

[Oracle® XML DB
Developer's Guide

11
g
 Release 2 (11.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094.pdf)  seems to indicate I should be using an XMLType and that I will need a xdb.jar and an  xmlparserv2.jar file

[Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) for the 11.2.0.2 and earlier seem to be missing the **xdb.jar** and **xmlparserv2.jar** files?

Where does one find these files To be able to correctly utilize the java import for "oracle.xdb.XMLType" for this version of 11g?

Comment: Do you have access to the server the database is running on?  You may find the JARs you need in `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` or perhaps `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib`.  Page 31-7 of the PDF you link to mentions the former location as where to find xmlparserv2 JAR and I found `xdb.jar` in the latter location (although I'm running XE so make of that what you will).

Comment: I currently don't have access to the server, but I did find that similar info yesterday and sent it to the database admins. @LukeWoodward your commment looks like an answer to me you should make it one...

Answer (score 1):

Try looking on the database server.

Page 31-7 of the [Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094.pdf) you linked to mentions that the xmlparserv2 JAR file can be found in `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`.  On my Oracle XE database I found a copy of xdb.jar under `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib`.  Having said that, though, XE is not a full Oracle database so I'm not promising that you'll find this JAR in the same location on your database.

If you have an Oracle client installed, you may also want to try looking in similar folders within the client installations.

Answer (score 0):

xdb6.jar is also available to download on the [JDBC download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)